# WHERE statment that CONTAINS a WILDCARD

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

Using MS SQL Server Studio

How would I use a WHERE CONTAINS, involving a wildcard.

This is what I have currently tried,

```
SELECT [Store No]
      ,[Store Name]
FROM [dbo].[EUACTIVESTORES] EU
WHERE CONTAINS ( EU.[Store Name], ''%UTO%' or '%HAM%'')
```

And also tried

```
SELECT [Store No]
   ,[Store Name]
    FROM [dbo].[EUACTIVESTORES] EU
WHERE EU.[Store Name] LIKE IN ('%UTO%','%HAM%')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `LIKE IN` but you can have `OR`

```
SELECT [Store No],[Store Name]
FROM [dbo].[EUACTIVESTORES] EU
WHERE 
EU.[Store Name] LIKE '%UTO%'
OR 
EU.[Store Name] LIKE '%HAM%
```

Or, try a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE nameLikes (
  like VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO likes VALUES ('%UTO%'), ('%HAM%');

SELECT EU.[Store No],[Store Name] 
FROM [dbo].[EUACTIVESTORES] EU
JOIN nameLikes n ON (EU.Name LIKE n.like);
```

Comment: Thank You, Was hoping there was a way to utilize the LIKE & IN together, just to save time if I had to write multiple ORs

Comment: @peterhinton see edit - you could join on a temp table

Comment: just saw that, this is exactly what I was hoping for !

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [Store No]
   ,[Store Name]
    FROM [dbo].[EUACTIVESTORES] EU
WHERE EU.[Store Name] LIKE '%UTO%' or EU.[Store Name] LIKE '%HAM%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OR` operator with two separate `LIKE` as below:

```
SELECT [Store No]
   ,[Store Name]
    FROM [dbo].[EUACTIVESTORES] EU
WHERE EU.[Store Name] LIKE '%UTO%' OR 
      EU.[Store Name] LIKE '%HAM%'
```